# SelectInput choices include column header

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, selectlist

I'm using shiny in a `.rmd` file and populating a `selectInput` choices list from a `.csv` file, taking unique values from a subset.

My problem is that the dropdown list is including the column header (= 'area' in my example below) which I don't want.

I've seen the links below and have tried a number of options (4 examples shown below), but I can't work out how to exclude the column header from the dropdown list.

[ https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1864 ]

[ https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/326 ]

[ https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html ]

Here is a cut down version of the data and code I'm using. (In my full version which reads in the `.csv` file, I included 'header=TRUE' in the `read.csv` statement but that didn't make a difference.)

````
---
output: html_document
resource_files:

runtime: shiny
---

```{r global_options, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)


library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(flexdashboard)
library(shinydashboard)

```

```{r data}

si_data <- structure(list(area = c("England", "England", "England", "North UHB", 
"North UHB", "North UHB", "South West UHB", "South West UHB", 
"South West UHB", "South UHB", "South UHB", "South UHB", "Hampshire", 
"Hampshire", "Hampshire", "South West UHB", "South West UHB", 
"South West UHB", "West UHB", "West UHB", "West UHB", "North West UHB", 
"North West UHB", "North West UHB", "North East UHB", "North East UHB", 
"North East UHB"), a_type = c("Country", "Country", "Country", 
"HB", "HB", "HB", "HB", "HB", "HB", "HB", "HB", "HB", "County", 
"County", "County", "HB", "HB", "HB", "HB", "HB", "HB", "HB", 
"HB", "HB", "HB", "HB", "HB"), order = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("area", "a_type", "order"
), row.names = c(NA, 27L), class = "data.frame")


```

```{r select input}

  fluidRow(
    column(width=8,
      inputPanel(width=400,
      selectInput("hb", label = "Select HB", choices = (unique(subset(si_data[order(si_data$order),], a_type=="HB",select=area))))
                            )))

  fluidRow(
    column(width=8,
      inputPanel(width='400px',
      selectInput("hb", label = "Select HB - naming the optgroup", choices = ('input_list'=unique(subset(si_data[order(si_data$order),], a_type=="HB",select=area))))
      )))

  fluidRow(
    column(width=8,
      inputPanel(width='400px',
      selectInput("hb", label = "Select HB - naming the optgroup, no quotes", choices = (input_list=unique(subset(si_data[order(si_data$order),], a_type=="HB",select=area))))
      )))

    fluidRow(
    column(width=8,
      inputPanel(width='400px',
      selectInput("hb", label = "Select HB - naming optgroup wrapped in a list", choices = (list("input_list"=unique(subset(si_data[order(si_data$order),], a_type=="HB",select=area))))
                            ))))

```
````

I'd be grateful for any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: This happens when you pass a dataframe column (which is a list) to the `choices` argument in `selectInput`. Just make sure you are passing a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the output of what choices you are passing to `selectInput`. You are passing a dataframe column (which is a list) and that's why you are seeing the column name in choices. This is actually a designed feature in case developers wanted to create sections in their choices.

```
(unique(subset(si_data[order(si_data$order),], a_type=="HB",select=area)))

             area
4       North UHB
22 North West UHB
25 North East UHB
10      South UHB
7  South West UHB
19       West UHB
```

If you don't need this, then just make sure you are passing a vector to choices. I have simplified your code for generating choices -

```
unique(si_data$area[order(si_data$order)][si_data$a_type == "HB"])

[1] "North UHB" "North West UHB" "North East UHB" "South West UHB" "West UHB" "Hampshire"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would alter your filtering in the following way, so I get the values straight forward values from the subset list:

```
unique(subset(si_data[order(si_data$order),], a_type=="HB",select=area))[[1]]
```